# Estimating Posterior in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, probability, bayesian, poisson

I'm new to Bayesian stats and I'm trying to estimate the posterior of a poisson (likelihood) and gamma distribution (prior) in Python. The parameter I'm trying to estimate is the lambda variable in the poisson distribution. I think the posterior will take the form of a gamma distribution (conjugate prior?) but I don't want to leverage that. The only thing I'm given is the data (named "my_data"). Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import scipy.stats 

x=np.linspace(1,len(my_data),len(my_data))
lambda_estimate=np.mean(my_data)

prior= scipy.stats.gamma.pdf(x,alpha,beta) #the parameters dont matter for now

likelihood_temp = lambda yi, a: scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(yi, a)
likelihood = lambda y, a: np.log(np.prod([likelihood_temp(data, a) for data in my_data]))

posterior=likelihood(my_data,lambda_estimate) * prior
```

When I try to plot the posterior I get an empty plot. I plotted the prior and it looks fine, so I think the issue is the likelihood. I took the log because the data is fairly large and I didn't want things to get unstable. Can anyone point out the issues in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://pypi.org/project/conjugate-prior/  ?

Answer (score 4):

In Bayesian statistics, one goal is to calculate the posterior distribution of the parameter (lambda) given the data and the prior over a range of possible values for lambda. In your code, you calculating the prior over the array x, but you are taking a single value for lambda to calculate the likelihood. The posterior and likelihood should be over x as well, something like:

```
posterior = [likelihood(my_data, lambda_i) for lambda_i in x] * prior
```

(assuming you are not taking the logs of the prior and likelihood)

You might want to take a look at the PyMC3 library.

Comment: Oh, I think you're right about the posterior, thanks for that. Unfortunately I cant use the PyMC3 library for this. Does my likelihood look right to you? I think that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at the `conjugate_prior` module.

You could just type:

```
from conjugate_prior import GammaPoisson
model = GammaPoisson(prior_a, prior_b)
model = model.update(...)
credible_interval = model.posterior(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

Comment: The last line gives an error:  tuple has no attribute posterior

Comment: That seem to work just fine, you can try it a one-liner:
`credible_interval =GammaPoisson(10, 20).update(10,10).posterior(9,11)`